# expandablelistview with mixed views

Tags: android

I'm trying to use ExpandableListView with three children in each group: the first two children contain text while the third one is an image. The code below displays the image on top of the first and the third children.
I appreciate your help in fixing this problem.

Here is my code:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        ImageView image;// = new ImageView();
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        if(childPosition==2)
        {
            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("photograph" , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(resID);
            return convertView;
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
        item.setText(laptop);
        return convertView;
    }
```

And here is the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/laptop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp" />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:contentDescription="image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    />
```

Comment: Can you post the full content of `child_item.xml`?

Comment: That is all except for this line : <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: No wonder: these elements are put one on top of the other. What happens if you use a `LinearLayout` instead?

Comment: @gunar I've changed the layout to LinearLayout and I still have the same problem. Thanks anyway.